# File linking with c++ makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, hyperlink

Make file:

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include/
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib

COMPILERFLAGS = -Wall
CC = g++
CFLAGS = $(COMPILERFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)
LIBRARIES = -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm

All: project

project: main.o landscape.o point.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I have a landscape.cpp, landscape.h, point.cpp, point.h, and main.cpp files
I'm including "point.h" in my main.cpp file and i'm getting:

g++ -Wall -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -o project -L/usr/X11R6/lib main.cpp -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm 
/tmp/ccdpJ8HH.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to`Point::Point(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'project' failed
make: *** [project] Error 1

Comment: You need to provide the object files to the line where you build the executable.

Comment: @BoBTFish I don't know what that means sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`project: main.o landscape.o point.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $< $(LIBRARIES)`

Here you need to link all .o files. The rule you have here will only use the main.o file. Because `$<`is the first dependency only. `$^` should be for all three. So try:

`project: main.o landscape.o point.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBDIR) $^ $(LIBRARIES)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a more complete Makefile.

Also, use `CXX=g++` and `CXXFLAGS` instead of `CC` and `CFLAGS`, because you are compiling C++ and `make` have special variables.

Here is an example of Makefile I could use.

```
# Project name
NAME=       project

# Include directory
INC_DIR=    /usr/X11R6/include/

# Library directory
LIB_DIR=    /usr/X11R6/lib/

# Compiler
CXX=        g++

# Source files
SRC_DIR=    # in case your cpp files are in a folder like src/

SRC_FILES=  main.c      \
            landscape.c \
            point.c

# Obj files
OBJ=        $($(addprefix $(SRC_DIR), $(SRC_FILES)):.c=.o)
# that rule is composed of two steps
#  addprefix, which add the content of SRC_DIR in front of every
#  word of SRC_FILES
#  And a second rule which change every ".c" extension into ".o"

LIBS=       X11 \
            Xi  \
            Xmu \
            glut    \
            GL  \
            GLU \
            m

# Compilation flags
CXXFLAGS=   -Wall

CXXFLAGS+=  $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIR))

LDFLAGS=    $(addprefix -L, $(LIB_DIR)) \
            $(addprefix -l, $(LIBS))

# Rules

# this rule is only linking, no CFLAGS required
$(NAME):    $(OBJ) # this force the Makefile to create the .o files
        $(CXX) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

All:    $(NAME)

# Remove all obj files
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ)

# Remove all obj files and the binary
fclean: clean
        rm -f $(NAME)

# Remove all and recompile
re: fclean all

# Rule to compile every .c file into .o
%.o:    %.c
        $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

# Describe all the rules who do not directly create a file
.PHONY: All clean fclean re
```

I'm not sure it's perfect, but it's better.
Also don't forget to put you project rule before your `All` rule to avoid relinking when simply calling `make`.

That way, you can also add beautiful messages (in the `%.o: %.c` rule for example).

With that you just have to do `make re` to get your binary fully updated.